# Selenium IDE clicking a button with changing name

Tags: jquery, selenium, selenium-ide

I need to click a button that's id suffix is changing every time I enter my site, so I saved the suffix in a variable and tried to merge it with it's prefix in order to click it later.

code: (suffix saved at btnCid)

```
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>id=btn+${btnCid}</td>
    <td>btnName</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>${btnName}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

It doesn't work and in the log I see it tried to find element called ${btnName} and not the name of the button saved there.
How can I click the wanted button?

Comment: Have you tried `<tr> <td>click</td> <td>id=btn+${btnCid}</td> <td></td> </tr>` ?

Comment: I tried, it leaves a blank space between them (id=btn ~valueOfbtn~) which is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use just:

```
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>//input[contains(@id, 'btn')]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```